# Vue.js - improving performance of infinite list loop

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, animation

I need a list of users to vertically loop infinitely. 
I know that I should use 'translateY' rather than 'top' for that kind of stuff - but I don't know how.
I've done the 'top' version and it works. Any ideas how to improve that?

Thanks guys!

[Example in Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjjNWK)

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="rows">
        <div class="row" v-for="row in rows" v-bind:style="{ top: row.top + 'px' }">
            {{row.id}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                rows: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                this.rows.push({
                    id: i,
                    top: i * 40
                })
            }
            setInterval(() => {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
            }, 16);
        },
        methods: {
            update() {
                this.rows.forEach(row => {
                    row.top -= 0.5
                });
                if (this.rows[0].top <= -40) {
                    this.rows.push({
                        id: this.rows[0].id,
                        top: (this.rows.length - 1) * 40
                    })
                    this.rows.shift();
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
<style>
    #rows {
        position: relative;
    }
    .row {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    const rows = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      rows.push({
        id: i
      })
    }

    return {
      offset: 0,
      rows
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.frameTime = Date.now()
    
    const animate = () => {
      this.animationId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.update()
        animate()
      })
    }
    
    animate()
  },
  
  beforeDestroy () {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationId)
  },

  methods: {
    update() {
      const now = Date.now()
      const elapsed = now - this.frameTime
      
      this.offset -= elapsed / 16
      this.frameTime = now

      if (this.offset < -400) {
        while (this.offset < -40) {
          this.rows.push(this.rows.shift())
          this.offset += 40
        }      
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rows {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="rows">
    <div :style="{ transform: `translateY(${Math.round(offset)}px)` }">
      <div
        v-for="row in rows"
        :key="row.id"
        class="row"
      >
        {{row.id}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't necessarily have to make all the changes I've made, most can be made selectively if you prefer. The major changes are:

1. Putting a `key` on the list items so Vue moves the DOM nodes rather than updating all of them when the shuffle occurs.
2. Using a wrapper `<div>` so that only one element is actually moving (I got rid of the absolute positioning as part of this).
3. Using `translateY`, as requested.
4. Getting rid of `setInterval`, you should only need `requestAnimationFrame` for this. The animation speed is kept in check by keeping track of how much time has elapsed.
5. When a row jumps I just move the object to the end of the array rather than making a copy.
6. The animation is cancelled when the component is destroyed.

**Update:**

Three further changes:

1. I've added `box-sizing: border-box` to fix the 2px inaccuracy in the calculations.
2. The DOM node reordering is now batched to only happen every 400px. No idea if this is actually a good idea, for such a simple example it doesn't really make any difference.
3. I've rounded the `translateY` to use whole pixels. For me this looked slightly better but on screens with higher pixel ratios I could imagine it might look worse.

There are further optimisations that might be applicable depending on the circumstances.

1. Rows that aren't visible could be omitted.
2. Reordering could be avoided altogether by applying the `translateY` to each row, though for large numbers of rows that may not be practical.

Animating this using transitions or CSS animations would be tricky due to the requirement for rows to jump back down to the bottom. If each row were animated independently I'm not sure how easy it would be to keep all the animations synchronised.

Comment: very elegant solution, thanks!

I had to change

`while (this.offset < -42) {
        this.rows.push(this.rows.shift())
        this.offset += 42
      }`

since the top and bottom 1px border was missing and it's been a bit shaky.

I made the mistake trying to animate the translateY property with a css transition - just setting it via javascript does the trick. 

is this version less cpu intensive than the version where I altered the top property?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can hear my MacBook's vents go off after some time running this.
Is this the caveat when not using the browser's CSS transform method but altering properties in while loops?

Comment: @uNki I don't know whether a pure CSS solution is possible here. Even if it is I wouldn't be surprised if your CPU fan kicks in doing it that way too. I would expect `translateY` to be less intensive than `top` but it would need a more complicated example (i.e. more DOM nodes) to really see what difference it makes. Performance tuning animations is a tightrope and it's very easy to undo all the optimisations with one innocuous-looking mistake.